# getting values from database error

Tags: php, database, forms, post

this is the form

```
<form action="manageservice.php" method="post">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="buy" value=”buy”>buy</button>
</form>
```

on submitting this it should go to next page manageservices.php
which has the following code

```
<?php 
          global $row;
          if(isset($_POST['buy']))
                                    {
                                        $id=$_POST['id'];
          $query5= "Select *from services where id = '$id' ; ";
          $result=mysqli_query($conn3,$query5) or die("Mysql error");

           while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                                        {
                                          ?>

          <!--Team Box Start-->
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <div class="team-box">
              <div class="thumb">
                <div class="team-hover">
                  <h6>Michelle WU</h6>
                  <p>Aliquam nec finibus dui, eget dapibus leo. Suspendisse aliquam, justo in venenatis congue, sem odio vestibulum lorem, quis consectetur arcu nulla in est. </p>
                  <div class="mayor-social"> <a class="fb" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a> <a class="tw" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a> <a class="lin" href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a> <a class="yt" href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a> </div>
                </div>
                <img src="images/timg-1.jpg" alt=""></div>
              <div class="team-txt">
                <h5><?php  echo $row['name'];?></h5>
                <p><?php  echo $row['email'];?></p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="loc-footer" style="background-color:#fff;">
                <ul>
                  <li class="loc-rating">4.98 <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i></li>
                  <li class="more">
                    <div class="btn-group dropup">
                      <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"> <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i> </button>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Send Email</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-commenting-o"></i> Send Message</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-compass"></i>Request a Call Back</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
          </div>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php } ?>
```

now when i am trying to implement this it shows blank space if i dont have id in quotes and a error undefined index if i put id in quotes and please help a important submission to be done

Answer (score 0):

There is no id input field in the Form.

so $id=$_POST['id']; will always be null.
Include an input field with name=id the type can be hidden, if you don't want to show it.

***UPDATE***

Code to do this is

```
<form action="manageservice.php" method="post"> 
  <input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $row6["id"];?>'> 
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="buy" value='buy'> 
     buy
  </button> 
</form>
```

Comment: can you ttell me how exactly i should change the code

Comment: <form action="manageservice.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="buy" value=”buy” />
<input type='hidden' value=".$row6['id']" name='id'>;

Comment: @umangyadav did you mean that literally you have an input hidden with `value=".$row6['id']"` in your HTML form?

Comment: <form action="manageservice.php" method="post">
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $row6['id'];?>'>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="buy" value=”buy”>buy</button>
</form>

Worth noting that this will only work if $row6['id'] has the id value. If it is blank, then you need to troubleshoot why $row6[id] is blank